# ¿Como crear una url personalizada en htaccess?

Tags: php, .htaccess

Estoy intentando usar una url personalizada parecida a algo que tiene wordpress para un sitio web que estoy creando.

La url actual es:

https://www.example.com/single-page.php?slug=example-page-slug

Y la quiero mostrar asi:

https://www.example.com/example-page-slug

Esto es posible? como lo puedo hacer?

He probado esta rule pero no me funciona:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)$ /single-page.php/?slug=$1&%{QUERY_STRING} [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Options -Multiviews
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
```

así me funciona a mi al trabajandolo en mvc.
el index.php es mi plantilla en tu caso usarias single-page.php